# Best Android Scheduler to Update UI

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android and working on this chat app where I want to change an Activity element based on a predetermined data on predetermined exact times. It doesn't have to work when app or phone is closed but I want to send notifications as well with the change. There is AlarmManager, JobScheduler, Handler, Timer, WorkManager but I am extremely confused about how they compare to each other. Which is the best option in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, `WorkManager` under the hood uses all of these scheduling APIs depending on the API level. This means that you won't have to deal with finding the best API for devices, because `WorkManager` will pick up the appropriate API for you.

You can also read the official documentation for more info and comparison: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

> The WorkManager API is a suitable and recommended replacement for all
> previous Android background scheduling APIs, including
> FirebaseJobDispatcher, GcmNetworkManager, and Job Scheduler.

Comment: I read that and thought, it could be an overkill and cause other problems such as battery drainage since it says 'background scheduling'. Does it make the necessary optimization based on the code and its requirements?

Comment: @EmreErkaslan you can achieve such things with WorkManager's Contraints. In addition to that, WorkManager is the recommended solution for background execution, taking into account all OS background execution limits. Another nice feature of WorkManager is that it respects power-management features, so that if a job is scheduled to run at a defined time and the device is in Doze at that time, WorkManager will try to run the task during a maintenance window if the constraints are met or after Doze is lifted.